# How to avoid/prevent Aborted Connections in mysql

Tags: mysql-5.1, connections

We are using `MySQL Version 5.1.73`. Database is getting huge number of connections around 600 at one time.

I observed `Aborted Connections` are getting increased from `Global Status` variables. So I enabled `log_warnings=2` and when I checked MySQL log file, I  observed huge number of below warnings:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 21352666 to db: 'DBName' user: 'UserName'
>   host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (Got an error reading communication packets)

I searched in Google and increased `max_allowed_packet` to 250 MB.

```
DB Size is 700 MB.
Innodb_log_file_size is 50 MB.
```

We also observed error like `'lost connection to MYSQL server at 'reading authorization packet' system error 0'` in application log files.

Why are we getting these warnings and errors and what to do to avoid them?

Answer (score 1):

All aborted connections tells you is the number of aborted connections.  It doesn't tell you why they didn't connect.

Do you have some kind of monitoring system or network scanning system in place?  e.g. Nagios, Spiceworks?  They will/can make a connection to the database network socket, then either not authenticate or fail to authenticate because they haven't been configured correctly.

These would cause the value of aborted connections to rise every time they attempt a connection, which could be very frequently.

Comment: Phil, I am aware of Aborted Connections status variable. But wanted to know why this many number of warnings.

Comment: So, do you have something in place that may be connecting automatically to check if the service is there - making connections and not authenticating properly?